# Как сохранить настройки Sublime text 3 перед форматированием

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3, configuration

Скачал много плагинов, и многие настройки поменял в *Sublime Text 3*, 
терять это все не хочу.
Как сохранить **эти настройки** и **историю плагинов**, для дальнейшего использования
 *на этом* или *на других* компьютерах **?**

Есть ли возможность сохранить настройки на github **?**

Comment: вероятно, эту задачу можно решить только с помощью скриншотов

Comment: Я использую портативную версию, и все установленные плагины и мои настойки лежат в папке "Data".